# Goobric Script Error

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling

I have been getting the pictured email for 3 weeks now.  I have remove and reinstalled both `Goobric` and `Doctopus` to see if it would fix the error. I have attempted to debug as well to no avail.  I know nothing of coding or script writing but I am willing to try anything to stop getting these.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I have this problem too, and "click here" takes me to a URL in my company's google apps domain, but the URL gives an error "Forbidden, Error 403".  I do not have Goobric as a file, or an add-on to any document in my Google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says "click here" you will be led to a place where you can remove the time trigger that is causing this notification.